# Function doesn't return more than two values

Tags: r, function, unit-testing, mocking, testthat

I'm working with unit testing using testthat in R. I have to test a function say calculateProfit. My function to test looks like this,

```
calculateProfit = function(subTotal, colName) {
  data  = getMappingList(subTotal, "dclass", colName)

  costRate = 0
  if (colName == "amount") {
    data_pt  = getMappingList(subTotal, "dclass", profit)
    costRate = -1 * (data_pt[COST] + data[COST]) / (data_pt[S] + data[S]) - -1 * data_pt[COST] / data_pt[S]
  }
```

The function getMappingList is as follows:

```
getMappingList = function(data, nameCol, valueCol) {
  nameList  = pull(data, nameCol)
  valueList = pull(data, valueCol)
  names(valueList) = nameList
  valueList
}
```

Now, while doing unit testing we have to mock the function getMappingList using local_mock from testthat. If the function getMappingList is called once then it is easy to test it. But since this function is called again I have used it like the below manner.

```
local_mock(getMappingList = function(data, nameCol, valueCol){
              data = read.csv(filePath = file.path(TARGET_PATH, "getMappingList", "Case1", "data.csv"))
              data = unlist(data)
              
              data_pt = read.csv(filePath = file.path(TARGET_PATH, "getMappingList", "Case1", "data_pt.csv"))
              data_pt = unlist(data_pt)
              
              return(data)
              return(data_pt)
              })
```

when I execute the actual script like below,

```
Actual_Output = calculateProfit(subTotal, "amount")
```

The if loop isn't executed. I'm getting the output for costRate as 0. But the output should be a whole number.

This is the input

```
> dput(subtotal)
structure(list(dclass = c("cost", "s"), amount = c(200, 300), 
    profit = c(301, 401)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

If anyone could help me to sort this out, it would be a great help.

Comment: You can return a list `return(list(data,data_pt))`

Comment: Yes I tried that as well but it is leading to another error like this "Error in data_pt[COST] + data[COST] : non-numeric argument to binary operator".

Comment: That is a different thing and has less to do with `return`, check if your data is numeric.

Comment: Ok I get it. The datatype is double.